# Display total values for similar key for on array of objects in angular table(ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of object that I want to display with ng-repeat then display the sum of the similar keys(noted that some of the keys are different). Here is my code :

```
let group =[  
   {  
      name:'Brandon Pack',
      city:NY,
      purchase:25,
      accepted:true
   },
   {  
      name:'Josh Vilet',
      city:Memphis,
      purchase:30,
      accepted:true
   },
   {  
      name:'Brandon Pack',
      city:NY,
      purchase:62,
      accepted:true
   },
   {  
      name:'Patrick Whiteside',
      city:NY,
      purchase:50,
      accepted:false
   },
   {  
      name:'Josh Vilet',
      city:Memphis,
      purchase:50,
      accepted:true
   }
]
```

I would like to display the total purchase after adding up each person's total purchase inside an ng-repeat:
Name

```
Brandon Pack 
Total purchase : 87
Josh Vilet
Total Purchase : 80
Patrick Whiteside
Total purchase: 50
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can use `group.reduce` to get an object containing all of the names an purchases.  After that, `ng-repeat` over that value's `obect.keys`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment suggested; you can use reduce:

```js
let group =[  
  {  
     name:'Brandon Pack',
     city:"NY",
     purchase:25,
     accepted:true
  },
  {  
     name:'Josh Vilet',
     city:"Memphis",
     purchase:30,
     accepted:true
  },
  {  
     name:'Brandon Pack',
     city:"NY",
     purchase:62,
     accepted:true
  },
  {  
     name:'Patrick Whiteside',
     city:"NY",
     purchase:50,
     accepted:false
  },
  {  
     name:'Josh Vilet',
     city:"Memphis",
     purchase:50,
     accepted:true
  }
]

let totals = group.reduce(
  (result,item)=>{
    result[item.name]=result[item.name]||0;
    result[item.name]=result[item.name]+item.purchase;
    return result;
  },
  {}
);

console.log(totals);
```